# TypeScript array equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, http, data-structures, typescript

I have this array in TypeScript:

```
public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
  {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}
];
```

How would I go about creating the equivalent in C#? I'm new to TypeScript and have never come across the 'any' type.

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Comment: what is the purpose of needing to match the two up? Are you sending this object to the client browser for javascript to use?

Comment: My fault - TypeScript not JavaScript. I'm converting some existing TypeScript code to C#.

Comment: What have you tried? What part exactly do you want to be "equivalent"? What C# code do you currently have and where are you stuck? Did you try searching the web for ["typescript any type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any)?

Comment: Well right now I have some code that populates an array of System.Drawing.PointF. My ultimate goal is to take those points and add them as the 'data' portion and give them a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With anonymous types you could have

```
var lineChartData = new [] {
    new { data = new [] { 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40 }, label = "Series A" },
    new { data = new [] { 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40 }, label = "Series B" }
};
```

That looks quite close to the Typescript version presented in the question.

Comment: How would you label a function that returns this anonymous type? I know labeling a functions return type as 'object' would work, but is there a more explicit way?

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to return it from a method you'd have to make the item type explicit and return an array of the explicit type or return an array of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be something like this in C#:

```
var lineChartData = new List<DataLine>
{
    new DataLine {Data = new[] {65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40}, Label = "Series A"},
    new DataLine {Data = new[] {28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90}, Label = "Series B"},
    new DataLine {Data = new[] {18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40}, Label = "Series C"}
};
```

And every line of your LineChartData will be something like this:

```
class DataLine
{
    public int[] Data { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Well yes, this structure can hold the same data as OP's TypeScript code, but it is not equivalent. `dynamic` or an anonymous object would be.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're right but I'm assuming he just want `Data` and `Label` and they are an array and a string respectively. If he wants something more *dynamic* and TypeScript like then `dynamic` is the way to go.

Comment: _"I'm assuming he just"_ - yeah, so the question is unclear. We don't know what the OP wants to do _exactly_.